# PHP mysql query SELECT returns object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to retrieve a value from a specific field inside a row, but the query returns an object.

```
$playernotifica = mysqli_query($db,'SELECT notifica 
FROM pontos WHERE nome = "'.$player['name'].'"');

var_dump($playernotifica);
```

var_dump returned the following:

*object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) } **notifica = 1***

"**notifica**" is the field, I need to retrieve just the "**1**" as a string.

Comment: Also, see about prepared and bound queries in php

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the mysqli query
   `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($playernotifica,MYSQLI_ASSOC);`
And then you can echo 
 `echo $row['notifica'];`
This will return what you need

Comment: ```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($temp,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$playernotifica = strval($row['notifica']);
```
That worked! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to call [Fetch Array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) to get the query result

```php
<?php
$row = $playernotifica->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$row['notifica'];
```